# how to get the particular sub view id from the view in android?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-view

I created a dynamic view that contains `FrameLayout`, and it contains `ImageView`s. Now, when I touch the particular image on frame layout, I want know the ID of the `ImageView`.

So, here are my questions:

1. How can I set the ID for the `ImageView`?
2. How can I recognize particular `ImageView` is touched?

Here is the sample snippet of the code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < _pageslist.size(); j++) {
    FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(HLActivity.this);
    LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    frame.setLayoutParams(params);

    ImageView mainimage = new ImageView(HLActivity.this);

    mainimage.setImageBitmap(ReusableMethods.getBitmapFromURL(_pageslist.get(j)
            .getThumbnail().toString()));
    mainimage.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    mainimage.setLayoutParams(params);

    frame.addView(mainimage, params);

    if (_pageslist.get(j).isHasspots()) {
        System.out.println(_pageslist.get(j).isHasspots());
        System.out.println(_pageslist.get(j).getSPOTS());

        ArrayList<Hotspot> hotspots_array = _pageslist.get(j).getSPOTS();
        for (int i = 0; i < hotspots_array.size(); i++) {
            Hotspot hotspot = hotspots_array.get(i);
            System.out.println("hotspot :: " + hotspot.getType());

            ImageView spotimage = new ImageView(HLActivity.this);
            spotimage.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#88676767"));

            float startx, starty, endx, endy;
            startx = (float) (Float.parseFloat(hotspot.getX()) * ivw) / 100;
            starty = (float) (Float.parseFloat(hotspot.getY()) * ivh) / 100;
            endx = (float) ((Float.parseFloat(hotspot.getX()) + 
                    Float.parseFloat(hotspot.getWidth())) * ivw) / 100;
            endy = (float) ((Float.parseFloat(hotspot.getY()) + 
                    Float.parseFloat(hotspot.getHeight())) * ivh) / 100;

            params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    (int) ((Float.parseFloat(hotspot.getWidth()) * ivw)/100),
                    (int) ((Float.parseFloat(hotspot.getHeight()) * ivh)/100));

            params.leftMargin = (int) startx;
            params.topMargin = (int) starty;

            frame.addView(spotimage, params);
        }
    }
    _view.add(frame);
}

adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(HLActivity.this, _view,
        _pageslist, ivw, ivh, getStatusBarHeight());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: how to set id? maybe use View.setId() method?

Comment: Set an on click or on touch listener on the views.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set ontouch listener to your image:

```
yourImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // this is your id you can pass it
            v.getId()
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: @user2745781 please except the answer if it helped you or tell your latest status of problem

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to identify the view which is touched, you can add listeners to your dynamic image views also. Like below

```
spotimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {`           
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
```

and in the onClick methord you can write code specific to each image view, or if you strictly want to set the id for image views, you can use
 `spotimage.setId(1)`

Id can be any integer value, but you have to make sure no conflict will occur with other id values. and in any listener like OnClickListenet, you can check the image view id by
`int temp = view.getId();`